# Json encode PRETTY PRINT printing out with slashes in php

Tags: php, json

I've followed all the tutorials on printing out a nicely formatted JSON response, but I can't get it to work. If I don't do json_encode PRETTY PRINT, it prints out as a raw JSON result in a single line,

But when I do add all that, it still prints it out as a single line, but with slashes before every quotation mark.

Heres the code I'm using

```
echo"<pre>";
$response = wp_remote_get( 'URL TO JSON DATA' ));
$jsonData = json_encode($response['body'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonData;
echo"</pre>";
```

And heres a sample of the data being printed out

`"{\"head\": {\"error\": \"\", \"version\": \"`

I can provide real data if necessary, I just wanted to show what I meant by a slash before every quotation, I'm hoping that's enough to give an idea of my problem

Thanks!

Comment: Those are so it can be parsed by php.

Comment: so how do I print out a nice looking json response inside the pre tag so its easy to read instead of one big chunk of code?

Comment: Code isn't meant to be be pretty by nature. It's meant to be functional. You can use JSON formatters online to make them easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you get from `wp_remote_get` is already a perfectly encoded JSON string, no need to encode again.

When you encode again, PHP generates a structure with one element, the string you originally get, and escapes all the quotes to form valid JSON.

So you can output the data directly :

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'URL TO JSON DATA' ));
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response;
```

Comment: Thanks, that removed the slashes when echoed out as $response['body']; but still prints out as a single line inside the  <pre>

Comment: if echoed out directly as $response like you suggested, is just print out the word array

Comment: Ok, if you really want the pretty print, decode it first, and re-encode it with pretty print option : `json_encode(json_decode($response['body'], true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`